# compare sum and sum of different conditions - post union processing?

Tags: neo4j

Hi I have a relationship Artist - Collaborated -> Writer and would like to find who are the artists who write mainly their own songs. Thus the weighted edge between writer and artist with the same name should be bigger than the sum of all other weights.

I managed to do this:

```
MATCH (n:Artist)-[r:Collaborated]-(m:Writer)
WITH n, m, sum(r.weight) as wrote
WHERE n.name = toLower(m.name) 
RETURN n.name as Node, wrote ORDER BY wrote descending;
```

but I am not sure how to incorporate the second condition. Do I have to use post union processing? Any help pls?

To join the two WHERE conditions, I tried something like this and compare the first sum to the second sum but it doesn't work:

```
MATCH (o:Artist)-[q:Collaborated]-(p:Writer)
WITH o, p, sum(q.weight) as wrote1
WHERE o.name <> toLower(p.name) 
MATCH (n:Artist)-[r:Collaborated]-(m:Writer)
WITH n, m, sum(r.weight) as wrote2
WHERE n.name = toLower(m.name)  and wrote2>wrote1
RETURN n.name as Node, wrote2;
```

This is an example of how my graph looks like:

[image]

I would like to know if the weight between eminem and eminem is bigger than all the other weights

Comment: Can you give us a graph example (by creating a neo4j console for example ) ? Because here, your query is in adequate with what you described ... so I think I have missed something

Comment: I added an example of what I want but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your model is a little weird, you have two nodes `Eminem`, one with the label `Artist` and an other with the label `Writer`.
For my POV, you should have only one node `Eminem` with both labels.

To respond to your question I think that this query can helps you :

```
MATCH (o:Artist)-[r:Collaborated]->(p:Writer)
WITH o, CASE WHEN o.name = p.name THEN r.weight ELSE -1*r.weight END AS score
RETURN o, sum(score) AS score
```

If the score is superior to `0`, then you know that `eminem and eminem is bigger than all the other weights`.